# Why won't these photos scale?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a template and I have a few pages i'm working on. There is a photo section at the top of each page. When I put an image into the css class, the image is enormous and wont scale to the frame.

The image is located in the id tag #subheader.

All the other photo sections of this template work just fine, everything scales perfectly. Im not understanding why this is happening here.

Heres a photo of what it looks like. This is the top left part of the image 
[image: photo]

```css
    #subheader {padding-bottom: 70px;
                background: #222;background:url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/shutterstock_134687783.jpg)top fixed;}
```

```html
     <!-- subheader -->
      <section id="subheader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h1>
                About Us
              </h1>
            </div>
            
            <!-- devider -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="devider-page">
                <div class="devider-img-right">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <ul class="subdetail">
                <li>
                  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li class="sep">/
                </li>

                <li>About
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- subheader end -->
```

Comment: hi could you put image  of your problem

Comment: i cant seem to do it in a comment, but I edited my post with a photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like this apply this then change position of cover size

```
#subheader {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    background: url(./img7.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: round;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did that before, i hope this works for you

```
background: url("--YOUR IMAGE HERE--") 50% 0% / cover no-repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```